# \# not supplying command number in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to print the number of commands in bash using \#. I have `printf 'This is command number'` and then when I put \# it just prints 'This is command number'. How do I use this prompt to print the command number?

Comment: This might be better suited for [Unix.se]

Comment: `\#` refers to the `PS1` prompt variable. Are you manipulating `PS1`?

Comment: Example: `PS1='Cmd \# \w \$ '` would display something like `Cmd 10 ~/path/to/dir $ ` as the prompt.

Comment: What do you mean by "command number"? The shell history line number, the line number of the shell script, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

`\#` only represents the current command number in the context of prompt expansion. Since `bash` 4.4, though, you can use the `@` operator to expand prompt escapes in an arbitrary parameter expansion.

```
$ x='Command number \#'
$ echo "$x"
Command number \#
$ echo "${x@P}"
Command number 4
```